# How to delete row in DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```
 foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
  if (row["ProductID"].ToString().Equals(txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
  {
    row.Delete();
    txtBarcode.Clear();

  }
 }
 adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idText", txtBarcode.Text);
 adapt.Fill(dt);
 dgItems.ReadOnly = true;
 dgItems.DataSource = dt;
 txtBarcode.Clear();
```

I am using this code to delete row when user try to insert the same barcode when it exist in the gridview, however there is an error. at first when i entered duplicate barcode it delete the row but when i entered another duplicate barcode it says `An unhandled exception of type System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

`Additional information: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.`

Comment: Try to invoke the row.AcceptChanges() after row.Delete() this will commit all changes made to the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
      if (row["ProductID"].ToString().Equals(txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
      {
        row.Delete();
        txtBarcode.Clear();

      }
     }
   dt.AcceptChanges();
```